# A specified Include path is not valid on eager loading

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, eager-loading

I am using eager loading in entity framework. My Model class is like

```
public class EmployeeMaster : AbsCommonParameters
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string EmpId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Employee name is required")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Employee geography is required")]
    public string Geography { get; set; }

    public string EmailId { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Column(TypeName = "Date")]
    [Display(Name = "Date Of Joining")]
    public Nullable<DateTime> DOJ { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Employee designation is required")]
    public string Designation { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public List<CenterMaster> lstCenters { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public List<CostCodeMaster> lstCostCode { get; set; }

}
```

In Controller Index Action my Code is like this

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   var lstUser = db.ObjEmployeeMaster.Include(p => p.lstCenters).
   Include(p => p.lstCostCode).Where(x => x.DeletedStatus == false).ToList();
   return View(lstUser);
}
```

Also In `DBContext` Constructor I have used

```
this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

After this I got error

> A specified Include path is not valid

Please help where I am wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Both collections are marked as `[NotMapped]`

Comment: `NotMappedAttribute` affects ability for a property to be included in entity model, since `Include` method intended to include entities. Try removing those attributes first.

Comment: @IvanStoev : Thanks for help.I got your answer.If I remove `[NotMapped]` that create an foreign key `EmployeeMaster_Id` in both the table. Which will create problem in every insert module. Is there any other way ?

Comment: Eager (lazy, explicit) loading works only with relationships. And the only type of relationships supported by EF are FK relationships. So the question is, do you have FK relationships between your entities (presumably using another existing EF column)? Or in other words, if you were going to populate them manually with LINQ `Join`, what field would you use in the related table? May be showing the `CenterMaster` class would help presenting the use case.